# Horizontal ListView Stream

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-layout

I'm having trouble creating a horizontal `ListView` stream from Firebase.

Here is my code:

```
...
Column(
  children: [
    Container(
      height: 200.0,
      child: StreamBuilder(
        stream: Firestore.instance
          .collection('users')
          .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          int length = 0;
          if(snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data.documents != null)
            length = (snapshot.data.documents.length ?? 0);
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: length,
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListItemWidget(document: snapshot.data.documents[index],);
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
...
```

And I get this error:

```
I/flutter (28131): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY RENDERING LIBRARY ╞═════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (28131): The following assertion was thrown during performResize():
I/flutter (28131): Horizontal viewport was given unbounded width.
I/flutter (28131): Viewports expand in the scrolling direction to fill their container.In this case, a horizontal
I/flutter (28131): viewport was given an unlimited amount of horizontal space in which to expand. This situation
I/flutter (28131): typically happens when a scrollable widget is nested inside another scrollable widget.
I/flutter (28131): If this widget is always nested in a scrollable widget there is no need to use a viewport because
I/flutter (28131): there will always be enough horizontal space for the children. In this case, consider using a Row
I/flutter (28131): instead. Otherwise, consider using the "shrinkWrap" property (or a ShrinkWrappingViewport) to size
I/flutter (28131): the width of the viewport to the sum of the widths of its children.
I/flutter (28131): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (28131): #0      RenderViewport.performResize.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1159:15)
I/flutter (28131): #1      RenderViewport.performResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1186:6)
I/flutter (28131): #2      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1616:9)
I/flutter (28131): #3      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (28131): #4      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (28131): #5      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (28131): #6      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (28131): #7      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (28131): #8      RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (28131): #9      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (28131): #10     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (28131): #11     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (28131): #12     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (28131): #13     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (28131): #14     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (28131): #15     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (28131): #16     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (28131): #17     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (28131): #18     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (28131): #19     RenderConstrainedBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:262:13)
I/flutter (28131): #20     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (28131): #21     RenderPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/shifted_box.dart:199:11)
I/flutter (28131): #22     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (28131): #23     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:108:13)
I/flutter (28131): #24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (28131): #25     RenderSliverList.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_list.dart:164:27)
I/flutter (28131): #26     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (28131): #27     RenderSliverPadding.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:182:11)
I/flutter (28131): #28     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1631:7)
I/flutter (28131): #29     RenderViewportBase.layoutChildSequence (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:405:13)
I/flutter (28131): #30     RenderViewport._attemptLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1320:12)
I/flutter (28131): #31     RenderViewport.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:1238:20)
I/flutter (28131): #32     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1506:7)
I/flutter (28131): #33     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:765:18)
I/flutter (28131): #34     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:270:19)
I/flutter (28131): #35     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:654:13)
I/flutter (28131): #36     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:208:5)
I/flutter (28131): #37     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:990:15)
I/flutter (28131): #38     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:930:9)
I/flutter (28131): #39     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:842:5)
I/flutter (28131): #40     _invoke (dart:ui/hooks.dart:128:13)
I/flutter (28131): #41     _drawFrame (dart:ui/hooks.dart:117:3)
I/flutter (28131): The following RenderObject was being processed when the exception was fired:
I/flutter (28131):   RenderViewport#4cfa1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131):   creator: Viewport ← _ScrollableScope ← IgnorePointer-[GlobalKey#a76da] ← Semantics ← Listener ←
I/flutter (28131):   _GestureSemantics ← RawGestureDetector-[LabeledGlobalKey<RawGestureDetectorState>#8a47c] ←
I/flutter (28131):   _ScrollSemantics-[GlobalKey#cab19] ← RepaintBoundary ← CustomPaint ← RepaintBoundary ←
I/flutter (28131):   NotificationListener<ScrollNotification> ← ⋯
I/flutter (28131):   parentData: <none> (can use size)
I/flutter (28131):   constraints: BoxConstraints(0.0<=w<=Infinity, h=300.0)
I/flutter (28131):   size: MISSING
I/flutter (28131):   axisDirection: right
I/flutter (28131):   crossAxisDirection: down
I/flutter (28131):   offset: ScrollPositionWithSingleContext#8dfac(offset: 0.0, range: null..null, viewport: null,
I/flutter (28131):   ScrollableState, ClampingScrollPhysics, IdleScrollActivity#91939, ScrollDirection.idle)
I/flutter (28131):   anchor: 0.0
I/flutter (28131): This RenderObject had the following descendants (showing up to depth 5):
I/flutter (28131):   RenderSliverPadding#e80f1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131):     RenderSliverList#97084 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#4cfa1 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#4cfa1 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#df1eb relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#44b85 relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#96b35 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#80416 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderScrollSemantics#712c9 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#aaf0f relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#a9537 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderListTile#6d051 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#9ebbd relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#0673a relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#4ee5a relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#36efb relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#3f9fc relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderListTile#fb3c8 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#db36b relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#56680 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#9a367 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#f9ea9 relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#18660 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 441 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: Horizontal viewport was given unbounded width.
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#e06d5 NEEDS-LAYOUT NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderViewport#e06d5 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderIgnorePointer#c9f49 relayoutBoundary=up13 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#710fd relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#40679 relayoutBoundary=up11 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#89057 relayoutBoundary=up10 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderScrollSemantics#fa9df relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#153a7 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderCustomPaint#31069 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#ba7c8 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderListTile#e1115 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#ba1c6 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#f49e3 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#28bc1 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#7e4cc relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#30f31 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: BoxConstraints forces an infinite width.
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: _RenderListTile#75a70 relayoutBoundary=up9 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#7e571 relayoutBoundary=up8 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsAnnotations#9dbc1 relayoutBoundary=up7 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPointerListener#59637 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderSemanticsGestureHandler#cbb7b relayoutBoundary=up5 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderFlex#ca6b6 relayoutBoundary=up4 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 441 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#ba7c8 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '<=' was called on null.
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 441 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: RenderBox was not laid out: RenderRepaintBoundary#687b9 relayoutBoundary=up6 NEEDS-PAINT
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The method '<=' was called on null.
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: 'package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart': Failed assertion: line 441 pos 12: 'child.hasSize': is not true.
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'visible' was called on null.
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.
I/flutter (28131): Another exception was thrown: Multiple widgets used the same GlobalKey.
E/flutter (28131): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (28131): Cannot hit test a render box with no size.
E/flutter (28131): The hitTest() method was called on this RenderBox:
E/flutter (28131):   RenderRepaintBoundary#a0721 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
E/flutter (28131): Although this node is not marked as needing layout, its size is not set. A RenderBox object must have an explicit size before it can be hit-tested. Make sure that the RenderBox in question sets its size during layout.
E/flutter (28131): #0      RenderBox.hitTest.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1911:9)
E/flutter (28131): #1      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1922:6)
E/flutter (28131): #2      _RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor&RenderSliver&ContainerRenderObjectMixin&RenderSliverHelpers.hitTestBoxChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:1471:22)
E/flutter (28131): #3      RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:455:11)
E/flutter (28131): #4      RenderSliver.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:1137:11)
E/flutter (28131): #5      RenderSliverPadding.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:266:20)
E/flutter (28131): #6      RenderSliver.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:1137:11)
E/flutter (28131): #7      RenderViewportBase.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:572:43)
E/flutter (28131): #8      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1924:11)
E/flutter (28131): #9      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:117:19)
E/flutter (28131): #10     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1924:11)
E/flutter (28131): #11     RenderIgnorePointer.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2780:37)
E/flutter (28131): #12     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:117:19)
E/flutter (28131): #13     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1924:11)
E/flutter (28131): #14     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:117:19)
E/flutter (28131): #15     RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:164:19)
E/flutter (28131): #16     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:117:19)
E/flutter (28131): #17     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1924:11)
E/flutter (28131): #18     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:117:19)
E/flutter (28131): #19     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1924:11)
E/flutter (28131): #20     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:117:19)
E/flutter (28131): #21     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1924:11)
E/flutter (28131): #22     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:117:19)
E/flutter (28131): #23     RenderCustomPaint.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:500:18)
E/flutter (28131): #24     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1924:11)
E/flutter (28131): #25     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:117:19)
E/flutter (28131): #26     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1924:11)
E/flutter (28131): #27     _RenderFlex&RenderBox&ContainerRenderObjectMixin&RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2250:17)
E/flutter (28131): #28     RenderFlex.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:925:12)
E/flutter (28131): #29     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1924:11)
E/flutter (28131): #30     _RenderStack&RenderBox&ContainerRenderObjectMixin&RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2250:17)
E/flutter (28131): #31     RenderStack.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:595:12)
E/flutter (28131): #32     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1924:11)
E/flutter (28131): #33     _RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox&RenderBox&Cont
E/flutter (28131): [ERROR:flutter/shell/common/shell.cc(181)] Dart Error: Unhandled exception:
E/flutter (28131): Cannot hit test a render box with no size.
E/flutter (28131): The hitTest() method was called on this RenderBox:
E/flutter (28131):   RenderRepaintBoundary#a0721 relayoutBoundary=up3 NEEDS-PAINT
E/flutter (28131): Although this node is not marked as needing layout, its size is not set. A RenderBox object must have an explicit size before it can be hit-tested. Make sure that the RenderBox in question sets its size during layout.
E/flutter (28131): #0      RenderBox.hitTest.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1911:9)
E/flutter (28131): #1      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1922:6)
E/flutter (28131): #2      _RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor&RenderSliver&ContainerRenderObjectMixin&RenderSliverHelpers.hitTestBoxChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:1471:22)
E/flutter (28131): #3      RenderSliverMultiBoxAdaptor.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_multi_box_adaptor.dart:455:11)
E/flutter (28131): #4      RenderSliver.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:1137:11)
E/flutter (28131): #5      RenderSliverPadding.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver_padding.dart:266:20)
E/flutter (28131): #6      RenderSliver.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/sliver.dart:1137:11)
E/flutter (28131): #7      RenderViewportBase.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/viewport.dart:572:43)
E/flutter (28131): #8      RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1924:11)
E/flutter (28131): #9      _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:117:19)
E/flutter (28131): #10     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1924:11)
E/flutter (28131): #11     RenderIgnorePointer.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:2780:37)
E/flutter (28131): #12     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:117:19)
E/flutter (28131): #13     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1924:11)
E/flutter (28131): #14     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:117:19)
E/flutter (28131): #15     RenderProxyBoxWithHitTestBehavior.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:164:19)
E/flutter (28131): #16     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:117:19)
E/flutter (28131): #17     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1924:11)
E/flutter (28131): #18     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:117:19)
E/flutter (28131): #19     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1924:11)
E/flutter (28131): #20     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:117:19)
E/flutter (28131): #21     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1924:11)
E/flutter (28131): #22     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:117:19)
E/flutter (28131): #23     RenderCustomPaint.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_paint.dart:500:18)
E/flutter (28131): #24     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1924:11)
E/flutter (28131): #25     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:117:19)
E/flutter (28131): #26     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1924:11)
E/flutter (28131): #27     _RenderFlex&RenderBox&ContainerRenderObjectMixin&RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2250:17)
E/flutter (28131): #28     RenderFlex.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/flex.dart:925:12)
E/flutter (28131): #29     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1924:11)
E/flutter (28131): #30     _RenderStack&RenderBox&ContainerRenderObjectMixin&RenderBoxContainerDefaultsMixin.defaultHitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:2250:17)
E/flutter (28131): #31     RenderStack.hitTestChildren (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:595:12)
E/flutter (28131): #32     RenderBox.hitTest (package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart:1924:11)
E/flutter (28131): #33     _RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox&RenderBox&Cont
```

But if I use a `scrollDirection: Axis.vertical` instead of `Axis.horizontal`, it works perfectly fine. Or if I use a regular `ListView` like this, it works too:

```
...
Column(
  children: [
    Container(
      height: 200.0,
      child: ListView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: [
          Container(width: 160.0, color: Colors.red,),
          Container(width: 160.0, color: Colors.orange,),
          Container(width: 160.0, color: Colors.pink,),
          Container(width: 160.0, color: Colors.yellow,),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
),
...
```

It feels like a silly question but I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: try on your Column a `crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch`, or `shrinkWrap` on ListView

Comment: I tried both, unfortunately I still get the same error.

Comment: Paste code of your ListItemWidget

Comment: @AndreyTurkovsky, The `ListItemWidget ` had a column and I forgot to wrap it with a container that has a set width. Problem solved. Thanks.

Comment: @ZviKarp would it be possible if you could show us a detailed answer on how you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The cause of this issue was `ListView` has been given an unconstrained width. Since the widget scrolls horizontally, a finite width should be defined. This error occurs when the widget is unable to fill a finite dimension on screen. You can either set a width on the `ListView` or try using an [`Expanded`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html) widget.

To fetch the screen's dimension for the width, you can either use [`LayoutBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/LayoutBuilder-class.html) or [`MediaQuery`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/MediaQuery-class.html).